# How to test a proxified websocket behind nginx?

Tags: shell, nginx, websocket

In my JS script, I use this to build a Websocket:

```
wss://IP/ws/rouLLuXiOjzvYgHkzNFfOmDDiSQajSLb
```

How can I test it in a shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have `node` and `npm` installed, you can use `wscat`:

```
# install
npm install -g wscat

# use
wscat -c "wss://${IP}/websocket-url"
```